# OmniAuth SAML getting logged in as previously authenticated user

Tags: gitlab, saml, omniauth, adfs

I have configued my GitLab CE application for SAML with ADFS. My IdP redirects and I get logged into GitLab using my SSO identity. It auto-creates a user. However, when another user attempts to log in, they get logged in as me.

```
gitlab_rails[‘omniauth_enabled’] = true

    gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['saml']

    gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false

    gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_saml_user'] = true

    gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [

      {

        name: 'saml',

        args: {

                assertion_consumer_service_url: 
'https://<domain>/users/auth/saml/callback',

                idp_cert_fingerprint: '<fingerprint>',

                idp_sso_target_url: 'https://<domain>/adfs/ls/',

                issuer: 'https://<domain>/adfs/services/trust',

                name_identifier_format: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent'

              },

        label: 'SAML Login' # optional label for SAML login button, defaults to &quot;Saml&quot;

      }

    ]
```

Any ideas what might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I had added the following in testing:
attribute_statements: { email: ['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress'] },
I removed this and my ADFS guy said "it was a claims transform mismatch" on his end.